# Effect of drinking on internal energy and entropy of the universe

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have just been doing some questions on thermodynamics and have come across a strange question that I can't seem to grasp.

The question asks me to estimate the change in body temperature as well as the entropy change of the universe when a man drinks a litre of 273 K cold beer in an **isolated** pub. I am given the mass of the man, as well as the specific heat capacity of water, and its density. I also am told to assume that the human body is mainly made up of water, and am given body temperature as 310 K.

I've been thinking that the answer must involve the fact that the pub is isolated and thus that the change in internal energy of the system is constant but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I have also derived earlier in the question that for a system at constant volume:

$$
\begin{align}
U(T_2) &= U(T_1) + \int_{T_1}^{T_2}C_V(T)\,\mathrm dT,\tag{1}\\
S(T_2) &= S(T_1) + \int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{C_V(T)}{T}\,\mathrm dT.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Any hints or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I took a liberty to replace a formulas screenshot with searchable text. Feel free to visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Also, I tried to narrow down the title and removed irrelevant "*question about*" part; however, since it looks somewhat cheesy, I'd be grateful if someone would go ahead and improve the title:)

Comment: I think they are asking you to evaluate the equilibration between a liter of beer at 273 K and a human body at 310 K (focusing exclusively on the thermal equilibration, and neglecting anything else that may be happening)).